# i would like to replace excel code to VBA format

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-word, vba6

=IF(AY2=AX2,AW2,"").
Can any please help me how to write theb above formula in excel VBA. I have already copied this formula in VBA, but the output shows '1004' error,

I have already copied this formula in VBA, but the output shows '1004' error,

Comment: Please share your code so we can better understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to write a formula or the result of the formula? Where will the result be located, e.g. `AV2` or `AV2:AVLastRow` or something else? An error is occurring. What is its description (there are many '1004-errors')?

Answer (score 1):

Use `IIF()` in VBA. Try-

```
Sub TestIIF()
    Debug.Print IIf(Range("AY2") = Range("AX2"), Range("AW2"), "")
End Sub
```